# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx-1}{n^2}$ for $x\in[2,5]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does this series converge uniformly or not?

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx-1}{n^2},\space x\in [2,5]$$

I know the Weierstrass M-test can be used to show if a series converges uniformly, but how would I show that my series does *not* converge uniformly?

Comment: When $x=2$, we get the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n-1}{n^2}$. This series is divergent.

Comment: Big hint: Limit test for convergence of sums.

Answer (score 1):

The series even doesn't converge.
Since $\frac{nx-1}{n^{2}}\geq\frac{nx-n}{n^{2}}=\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{n}\geq\frac{1}{n}$,
The series is always greater than or equal to the harmonic series, which diverges.